# How do we compute voltage drop across a capacitor?

Tags: operational-amplifier, capacitor, circuit-analysis

When we have an OpAmp, for instance

[image]

Then, how could I compute how VO1 (AC + DC) changes when passing across C2?

Comment: As drawn, assuming an ideal op amp, there will be no current into or out of C2. Therefore there can be no AC component across C2. On the other hand, the DC voltage across C2 can be any value, since (again) there is no AC component, and there is no way to change the charge differential on the capacitor.

Comment: By no AC component, do you mean that the AC voltage before and after C2 is the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your circuit is that there is no dc bias point at U2's +input and every op-amp needs to have one. This is easily rectified with a resistor from +input to ground. This means that C2 and the new resistor (RN) form a high pass filter with a cut-off frequency of \$\frac{1}{2\pi R_N C_2}\$.

[image]